# Populate datalist options asynchronously (fetch) on focus

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom

The idea is to not show the datalist, until it has fetched the data.

This updated list is available on the second focus.

**How can I get it to work on the first focus?**

https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-frost-kck0d?file=/src/index.js

```html
<input id="input" list="list" />
<datalist id="list">
    <option data-id="1" value="option 1"></option>
    <option data-id="2" value="option 2"></option>
    <option data-id="3" value="option 3"></option>
</datalist>
```

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("focus", () => {
  let datalist = document.getElementById("list");
  datalist.innerHTML = "";

  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.map(item => {
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("data-id", item.id);
        option.value = item.name;

        datalist.appendChild(option);
      });
    })
    .catch(err => err);
});
```

Comment: It does get called on the first focus. https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-tree-7hgis?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I'd like the fetched list to show on focus.

Comment: Any specific reason you want to `fetch` on focus? could you pre-fetch the list may be?

Comment: Well, if someone updates the list, I'd like the changes to be reflected without refreshing the page.

Comment: You mean you want the popup menu to open automatically?

Comment: No. I want the menu to show the downloaded values, but I want the download to happen on the input click. In other words, show the datalist after the download finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very weird behaviour on the `datalist`, I was able to get it working but it wasn't super straightforward and needed some workaround.

It currently works only if the ajax call responds before the the focus is fired,

```js
var padded = document.querySelector("#padded");
var input = document.querySelector("#input");

input.addEventListener("mouseover", evt => evt.stopImmediatePropagation());
padded.addEventListener("mouseover", async evt => {
  console.log(evt.currentTarget);
  let datalist = document.getElementById("list");
  datalist.innerHTML = "";
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const data = await response.json();
  data.forEach(item => {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("data-id", item.id);
    option.value = item.name;

    datalist.appendChild(option);
  });
  console.log("responded");
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#padded {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="padded">
  <input id="input" list="list" />
  <datalist id="list">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: Niiiiiice. Thank you for the solution. Wonder if there are any pitfalls.

Comment: @Ivan the only one I could find was if you click on the input before the call finishes.